# Tried to integrate AngularJS and three.js but the geometry is not getting rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js, rendering, integration

(this is an example which i found on the net but still it does not work fine).
I am trying to integrate AngularJS in order to get an MVC architecture for three.js files. Though I do not find any errors while debugging, I am not able to see any geometry(cube) getting rendered. 
My JS file.....

```
var newApp = angular.module('new', ['ngRoute','newServices']);

newApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider,     $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {templateUrl:"views/main.html", controller:'mainCtrl'});
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}]);


newApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'renderFactory', function ($scope, renderFactory) {
$scope.text = 'Hello';

init();
function init() {
    renderFactory.createCamera();
    renderFactory.createCube();
    renderFactory.setup();
    renderFactory.paint();

}

} ]);
```

**My factory file...**

```
var xrotation;
var yrotation;
var zrotation;
var WIDTH = 800;
var HEIGHT = 600;
var ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera;
var cube;

var newServices = angular.module('newServices', []);
newServices.factory('renderFactory', function () {
return {


    createCube: function () {
        // set up the cube vars
        var length = 50;
        var segments = 16;

        // create the cube's material
        var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000 });

        // create a new mesh with cube geometry -
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CubeGeometry(15, 15, 15), sphereMaterial);

        //Set Cube Rotation
        //cube.rotation.x += 0.2;
        //cube.rotation.y += 0.3;
        //cube.rotation.z += 0.1;

        scene.add(cube);

    },

    createCamera: function () {
        // set some camera attributes
        var VIEW_ANGLE = 40;
        var NEAR = 0.1;
        var FAR = 10000;

        // create a WebGL camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE,
                 ASPECT,
                 NEAR,
                 FAR);

        // the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
        //camera.position.z = 250;

        // and the camera
        scene.add(camera);

    },

    paint: function () {
        // draw!
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    },



    setup: function () {
        // start the renderer
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        document.getElementById('container1').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    }

};
});
```

Where did i go wrong??? or did i miss something??

Comment: where are you creating the scene?

Comment: sorry for that, i have added the entire factory now.

Answer (score 0):

I know far more about THREE than I know about Angular but I don't think a factory should be wrapped in a service.  As a factory, without the service, it works fine after a simple change that you already had in there: you were on the right track with "camera.position.z = 250;" but commented it out, it puts your camera at the same location as your cube so with the camera sitting in the middle of your cube leaves nothing to see but the transparent inside of a cube.

I took the factory out of the service and uncommented the camera position.  I also took out the router because the question regards Angular/Three not routers.

Here's the app section:

```
var newApp = angular.module('new', []);

newApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'renderFactory', function ($scope, renderFactory) {
    init();

    function init() {
        renderFactory.createCamera();
        renderFactory.createCube();
        renderFactory.setup();
        renderFactory.paint();
    }

}]);
```

In your factory, I removed it from the service wrapper and uncommented your camera position:

```
newApp.factory('renderFactory', function renderFactory() {
    var xrotation;
    var yrotation;
    var zrotation;
    var WIDTH = 800;
    var HEIGHT = 600;
    var ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera;
    var cube;

    return {
        createCube: function () {
        // set up the cube vars
        var length = 50;
        var segments = 16;

        // create the cube's material
        var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
            color: 0xFF0000
        });

        // create a new mesh with cube geometry -
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(15, 15, 15), sphereMaterial);

        //Set Cube Rotation
        cube.rotation.x += 0.2;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.3;
        cube.rotation.z += 0.1;

        scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFF0000));

        scene.add(cube);

    },
    createCamera: function () {
        // set some camera attributes
        var VIEW_ANGLE = 40;
        var NEAR = 0.1;
        var FAR = 10000;

        // create a WebGL camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE,
        ASPECT,
        NEAR,
        FAR);

        // the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
        camera.position.z = 250;

        // and the camera
        scene.add(camera);

    },
    paint: function () {
        // draw!
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    },
    setup: function () {
        // start the renderer
        renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
     document.getElementById('container1').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    }
};
```

});

The html, just for anyone curious, is simply:

```
<body ng-app="new">
    <div id="container1" ng-controller="mainCtrl"></div>
</body>
```

I also uncommented your cube rotations, makes it look less like a red square.

Here's a Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kkelly/ccfyL82k/

Answer (score 0):

I create a directive that it's working  I attached my directive but

in your code the line that has

```
 document.getElementById('container1').appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

you should try

```
    container = angular.element('#container1');                                         
    container.append(renderer.domElement);
```

this won't work on linking or angular WARNING appendchild undefined

```
 ` elem[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

or in a linkin function like my directive code below

```
 ` (function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('vr-module')
   .directive(
    "vr",vr);

    /* @ngInject */
    function vr() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl:'app/vr-module/vr.html',
            templateAs:'vr',
            controller:'VrPageController',
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

                // declarando las variables que conteneran los objectos de mi juego
                  var scene, camara, fieldOfView, aspectratio, nearPlane , farPlane,
                      renderer, container, ALTURA, ANCHO,mouseX,mouseY , mar, Mar, nube, Nubes, Cielo;

                      var Colors = {
                        red:0xf25346,
                        white:0xd8d0d1,
                        brown:0x59332e,
                        pink:0xF5986E,
                        brownDark:0x23190f,
                        blue:0x68c3c0,
                      };

                      function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                                     mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
                                     mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

                                 }

                      function crearLaEscena() {

                              ALTURA = window.innerHeight;
                              ANCHO = window.innerWidth;
                              // crear la escena
                              scene = new THREE.Scene();

                              // adicionar un efecto de niebla = Fog funcion
                              scene.niebla = new THREE.Fog(0xf7d9aa, 100, 950);

                              // crear la camara

                              aspectratio = ANCHO/ALTURA;
                              fieldOfView = 60;
                              nearPlane = 1;
                              farPlane =10000;
                              camara = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                                        fieldOfView,
                                        aspectratio,
                                        nearPlane,
                                        farPlane
                                      );

                              // posicionar la camara ne el espacio 3d x,y,z
                              camara.position.x = 0;
                              camara.position.z = 900;
                              camara.position.y = 100;

                              // ahora creare el dibujador de los graficos
                              renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({

                                // opcion de mostrar transparencia para que se vea
                                // el fondo degradado que se puso en el css
                                alpha : true,
                                antialias : true
                              });
                              // le damos el alto y ancho  de toda la pantalla
                              renderer.setSize(ANCHO, ALTURA);

                              // esto abilita la opcions de mostrar sombras
                              renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

                              // adicionar los elementos del dibujador renderer
                              // al contenedor creado en el html
                              // elem[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement);
                                            container = angular.element('#mi-mundo');
                                            // container =elem;


                            container.append(renderer.domElement);
                              // evento que supervisa si el usuario cambia el tamano de
                              // la pantalla entonces tenemos que actualizar la camara

                              window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false);

                              // end crear escena funcion
                            }

                      // esta es la funcion que se encarga de actualizar el cambio de
                      // tamano
                      function handleWindowResize() {
                        // a medida que va cambiando vamos actualizando
                        // el tamano del renderer y el aspectratio la camara
                        ALTURA = window.innerHeight;
                        ANCHO = window.innerWidth;
                        renderer.setSize(ALTURA, ANCHO);
                        camara.aspect =ANCHO/ALTURA;
                        camara.updateProjectionMatrix();
                      }

                      // AHORA luces
                      // una de la spartes mas dificiles es la luz de una escena
                      var hemisphereLight, shadowlight;

                      function crearLasLuces() {
                              // hemisphereLight es la luz degradada clara
                              // su primer parametro es el color del nube
                              // el segundo es el color del piso

                              // y el tercero es la intensidad de la luz
                              hemisphereLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xaaaaaa, 0x000000, .9);

                              // luz direccional, es la que brilla desde una posicion especifica
                              // va ser como el sol, osea que toda la luz va ser paralela

                              shadowlight =  new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .9);

                              // ahora le damos una direcion a la luz vectorialmente (x,y,z)
                              shadowlight.position.set(150,350,350);

                              // activar la opcion castShadow para que ;a luz produzca sombras
                              shadowlight.castShadow = true;

                              // ahora definimos el area de las sombras projectadas

                              shadowlight.shadow.camera.left = -400
                              shadowlight.shadow.camera.right = 400
                              shadowlight.shadow.camera.top = 400;
                              shadowlight.shadow.camera.bottom = -400
                              shadowlight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
                              shadowlight.shadow.camera.far = 1000;

                              // ahora definimos la resolucion de las sombras entre mas alta
                              // mejor pero tambine requiere mas de la computadora
                              shadowlight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
                              shadowlight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

                              // ahora para activar nuestras luces solo
                              // las adicionamos al ecenario :)

                              scene.add(hemisphereLight);
                              scene.add(shadowlight);

                            }

                      Mar = function () {

                        var geom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(600,600,800,40,10);
                        geom.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-Math.PI/2));
                        var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                          color:Colors.blue,
                          transparent:true,
                          opacity:.6,
                          shading:THREE.FlatShading,
                        });
                        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
                        this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;


                      }

                      function crearElMar() {
                        mar = new Mar();
                        //empujemos el cilindor en la parte de abajo del escenario
                        mar.mesh.position.y = -600;
                        // y lo ponemos ne el scenario
                        scene.add(mar.mesh);
                      }


                      Nubes = function () {
                        // creamos el solido
                        this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();

                        // crearemos un cubo geomtrico y lo duplicaremos
                        // para crear las NUBES
                        // var geom = THREE.BoxGeometry(20,20,20);
                        var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20,20,20);
                        var mat =new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                          color:Colors.white,
                        });

                        // duplicamos las NUBES
                        var nBlocs =  3+Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
                        for (var i=0; i<nBlocs; i++ ){

                          // create the mesh by cloning the geometry
                            var m = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);

                              // set the position and the rotation of each cube randomly
                            m.position.x = i*15;
                            m.position.y = Math.random()*10;
                            m.position.z = Math.random()*10;
                            m.rotation.z = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
                            m.rotation.y = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;

                            // set the size of the cube randomly
                            var s = .1 + Math.random()*.9;
                            m.scale.set(s,s,s);

                            // allow each cube to cast and to receive shadows
                            m.castShadow = true;
                            m.receiveShadow = true;

                            // add the cube to the container we first created
                            this.mesh.add(m);
                        }
                      }

                      Cielo = function (){
                          this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
                          this.nCLouds = 20;
                          this.clouds = [];
                          var stepAngle = Math.PI*2 / this.nCLouds;
                        // aqui crearemos las nubes
                        for (var i = 0; i < this.nCLouds; i++) {
                            var c = new Nubes();

                            this.clouds.push(c);
                            // les ponemos rotacion y posicion de cada nube
                            // con trigonometria

                            //el angulo de la nube
                            var a = stepAngle*i;
                            // la distancia entre el centro de la x y
                            // la nube misma
                            var h = 750 + Math.random()*200;

                            //trigonometricamente convertimos las coordenadas
                            // en coordenadaspolares

                            c.mesh.position.y = Math.sin(a)*h;
                            c.mesh.position.x = Math.cos(a)*h;

                            //ahora rotemos
                            c.mesh.rotation.z = -400-Math.random()*400;

                            // y le hacesmo diferente tamano para cada nube
                            var s = 1+Math.random()*2;
                            c.mesh.scale.set(s,s,s);

                            // ahora l aponemos en el escenario
                            this.mesh.add(c.mesh);
                        }

                      }
                        var cielo;
                       function CrearElCielo() {
                         cielo = new Cielo();
                         cielo.mesh.position.y = -600;
                          scene.add(cielo.mesh);

                      }

                      function crearElAeroPlano() {

                      }

                      function actualizarEscena(){
                        // updatePlane();
                        mar.mesh.rotation.z += .005;
                        cielo.mesh.rotation.z += .01;
                        renderer.render(scene, camara);
                        requestAnimationFrame(actualizarEscena);
                      }



                      function init() {
                        // creando el escenario, la camara, las luces y accion :)!!!
                        // setup scene, camera, render and lights
                        crearLaEscena();
                        crearLasLuces();
                        //insertando el avion (el objecto 3d), el mar, y el nube
                        // add moving objects
                        crearElAeroPlano();
                        crearElMar();
                        CrearElCielo();
                        // finalmente se repite cada scena para actualizarla
                        // se repite para mantener la escena render
                        actualizarEscena();
                      }

                            init();


                  // window.addEventListener('load',init, false);

            }
        }
    }
```

}());

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
  .module('vr-module')
  .directive(
  "vr",vr);

  /* @ngInject */
  function vr() {
   return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl:'app/vr-module/vr.html',
    templateAs:'vr',
    controller:'VrPageController',
    link: function (scope, elem, attr) {

     // declarando las variables que conteneran los objectos de mi juego
       var scene, camara, fieldOfView, aspectratio, nearPlane , farPlane,
           renderer, container, ALTURA, ANCHO,mouseX,mouseY , mar, Mar, nube, Nubes, Cielo;

           var Colors = {
            red:0xf25346,
            white:0xd8d0d1,
            brown:0x59332e,
            pink:0xF5986E,
            brownDark:0x23190f,
            blue:0x68c3c0,
           };

           function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                          mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX ) / 2;
                          mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY ) / 2;

                      }

           function crearLaEscena() {

                   ALTURA = window.innerHeight;
                   ANCHO = window.innerWidth;
                   // crear la escena
                   scene = new THREE.Scene();

                   // adicionar un efecto de niebla = Fog funcion
                   scene.niebla = new THREE.Fog(0xf7d9aa, 100, 950);

                   // crear la camara

                   aspectratio = ANCHO/ALTURA;
                   fieldOfView = 60;
                   nearPlane = 1;
                   farPlane =10000;
                   camara = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
                             fieldOfView,
                             aspectratio,
                             nearPlane,
                             farPlane
                           );

                   // posicionar la camara ne el espacio 3d x,y,z
                   camara.position.x = 0;
                   camara.position.z = 900;
                   camara.position.y = 100;

                   // ahora creare el dibujador de los graficos
                   renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({

                     // opcion de mostrar transparencia para que se vea
                     // el fondo degradado que se puso en el css
                     alpha : true,
                     antialias : true
                   });
                   // le damos el alto y ancho  de toda la pantalla
                   renderer.setSize(ANCHO, ALTURA);

                   // esto abilita la opcions de mostrar sombras
                   renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

                   // adicionar los elementos del dibujador renderer
                   // al contenedor creado en el html
                   // elem[0].appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            container = angular.element('#mi-mundo');
            // container =elem;


                    container.append(renderer.domElement);
                   // evento que supervisa si el usuario cambia el tamano de
                   // la pantalla entonces tenemos que actualizar la camara

                   window.addEventListener('resize', handleWindowResize, false);

                   // end crear escena funcion
                 }

           // esta es la funcion que se encarga de actualizar el cambio de
           // tamano
           function handleWindowResize() {
             // a medida que va cambiando vamos actualizando
             // el tamano del renderer y el aspectratio la camara
             ALTURA = window.innerHeight;
             ANCHO = window.innerWidth;
             renderer.setSize(ALTURA, ANCHO);
             camara.aspect =ANCHO/ALTURA;
             camara.updateProjectionMatrix();
           }

           // AHORA luces
           // una de la spartes mas dificiles es la luz de una escena
           var hemisphereLight, shadowlight;

           function crearLasLuces() {
                   // hemisphereLight es la luz degradada clara
                   // su primer parametro es el color del nube
                   // el segundo es el color del piso

                   // y el tercero es la intensidad de la luz
                   hemisphereLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xaaaaaa, 0x000000, .9);

                   // luz direccional, es la que brilla desde una posicion especifica
                   // va ser como el sol, osea que toda la luz va ser paralela

                   shadowlight =  new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, .9);

                   // ahora le damos una direcion a la luz vectorialmente (x,y,z)
                   shadowlight.position.set(150,350,350);

                   // activar la opcion castShadow para que ;a luz produzca sombras
                   shadowlight.castShadow = true;

                   // ahora definimos el area de las sombras projectadas

                   shadowlight.shadow.camera.left = -400
                   shadowlight.shadow.camera.right = 400
                   shadowlight.shadow.camera.top = 400;
                   shadowlight.shadow.camera.bottom = -400
                   shadowlight.shadow.camera.near = 1;
                   shadowlight.shadow.camera.far = 1000;

                   // ahora definimos la resolucion de las sombras entre mas alta
                   // mejor pero tambine requiere mas de la computadora
                   shadowlight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
                   shadowlight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

                   // ahora para activar nuestras luces solo
                   // las adicionamos al ecenario :)

                   scene.add(hemisphereLight);
                   scene.add(shadowlight);

                 }

           Mar = function () {

             var geom = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(600,600,800,40,10);
             geom.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-Math.PI/2));
             var mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
               color:Colors.blue,
               transparent:true,
               opacity:.6,
               shading:THREE.FlatShading,
             });
             this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);
             this.mesh.receiveShadow = true;


           }

           function crearElMar() {
             mar = new Mar();
             //empujemos el cilindor en la parte de abajo del escenario
             mar.mesh.position.y = -600;
             // y lo ponemos ne el scenario
             scene.add(mar.mesh);
           }


           Nubes = function () {
             // creamos el solido
             this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();

             // crearemos un cubo geomtrico y lo duplicaremos
             // para crear las NUBES
             // var geom = THREE.BoxGeometry(20,20,20);
             var geom = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20,20,20);
             var mat =new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
               color:Colors.white,
             });

             // duplicamos las NUBES
             var nBlocs =  3+Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
             for (var i=0; i<nBlocs; i++ ){

               // create the mesh by cloning the geometry
           var m = new THREE.Mesh(geom, mat);

             // set the position and the rotation of each cube randomly
             m.position.x = i*15;
             m.position.y = Math.random()*10;
             m.position.z = Math.random()*10;
             m.rotation.z = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;
             m.rotation.y = Math.random()*Math.PI*2;

             // set the size of the cube randomly
             var s = .1 + Math.random()*.9;
             m.scale.set(s,s,s);

             // allow each cube to cast and to receive shadows
             m.castShadow = true;
             m.receiveShadow = true;

             // add the cube to the container we first created
             this.mesh.add(m);
             }
           }

           Cielo = function (){
               this.mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
               this.nCLouds = 20;
               this.clouds = [];
               var stepAngle = Math.PI*2 / this.nCLouds;
             // aqui crearemos las nubes
             for (var i = 0; i < this.nCLouds; i++) {
                 var c = new Nubes();

                 this.clouds.push(c);
                 // les ponemos rotacion y posicion de cada nube
                 // con trigonometria

                 //el angulo de la nube
                 var a = stepAngle*i;
                 // la distancia entre el centro de la x y
                 // la nube misma
                 var h = 750 + Math.random()*200;

                 //trigonometricamente convertimos las coordenadas
                 // en coordenadaspolares

                 c.mesh.position.y = Math.sin(a)*h;
                 c.mesh.position.x = Math.cos(a)*h;

                 //ahora rotemos
                 c.mesh.rotation.z = -400-Math.random()*400;

                 // y le hacesmo diferente tamano para cada nube
                 var s = 1+Math.random()*2;
                 c.mesh.scale.set(s,s,s);

                 // ahora l aponemos en el escenario
                 this.mesh.add(c.mesh);
             }

           }
             var cielo;
            function CrearElCielo() {
              cielo = new Cielo();
              cielo.mesh.position.y = -600;
               scene.add(cielo.mesh);

           }

           function crearElAeroPlano() {

           }

           function actualizarEscena(){
             // updatePlane();
             mar.mesh.rotation.z += .005;
             cielo.mesh.rotation.z += .01;
             renderer.render(scene, camara);
             requestAnimationFrame(actualizarEscena);
           }



           function init() {
             // creando el escenario, la camara, las luces y accion :)!!!
             // setup scene, camera, render and lights
             crearLaEscena();
             crearLasLuces();
             //insertando el avion (el objecto 3d), el mar, y el nube
             // add moving objects
             crearElAeroPlano();
             crearElMar();
             CrearElCielo();
             // finalmente se repite cada scena para actualizarla
             // se repite para mantener la escena render
             actualizarEscena();
           }

        init();


       // window.addEventListener('load',init, false);

    }
   }
  }
}());
```